# Why are my pings to websites now being timed out?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, cmd.exe, timeout

Only recently, pinging a website through the CMD will result in a timeout for all four attempts. As I mentioned, this has only started happening within the last week or so. Before I could ping google, facebook, youtube etc. over and over with results. Why would this suddenly start happening? Nothing has changed on our end that I know of. I can still access websites fine, but pinging doesn't bring back a result.

Also, not sure if it's related, when logged into the router it says it's not connected to the internet, but it clearly is. Why would this be happening? Are they related? 
All help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Three possibilities off the top of my head:

1) ICMP is being blocked somewhere along the way. Try to find a tcpping tool for your platform to see if this makes a difference.

2) Packet loss. Try with more than just four pings. On windows this means adding the -t switch: `ping -t 4.2.2.2` (or some other hostname or address). If you eventually get some coming through, it means that you're having a bad case of packet loss, and it's indicative of a larger problem somewhere.

3) You happen to be pinging a hostname that doesn't respond to pings for a variety of reasons. This can probably be outruled since I can ping both facebook and google just fine. (which I knew before I tested it).

---

I suspect *#2* is your problem, as packetloss often manifests itself this way, plus your router fails to realize that it's connected even though it is. A common fix is to powercycle all networking hardware, routers and modems in particular. While it's not a guaranteed fix, it does often help to just let your hardware takea a 5 second break now and then.

If still no luck, query your ISP about your uplink quality. Often they won't know something is wrong before looking into issues like these.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't expect to get such a detailed response so quickly.

1) I'm not 100% sure how I'd go about finding when and where the ICMP is being blocked. 
2) I've been pinging an address for the past 5 minutes and they've all timed out. 
I'll give my ISP a call tomorrow and see what they can do about it I suppose.

Comment: @Forumpy 
1) Traceroute (`tracert`)
2) Either not packet loss, or really really bad packetloss to the point where you'd notice issues with browsing too

Comment: 1) Traceroute (`tracert` in windows)
2) Either it's not packet loss, or as I suspect, really really bad packet loss

Answer (score 0):

There's no particular reason you should be able to ping a web site. Web sites are intended to respond to HTTP queries and they may or may not respond to pings. Unless you know for a fact that there's some reason it should work, it shouldn't concern or surprise you if it doesn't.